# I need to write "If the value of the cell in column named "well" = "A01" add the data from column named "Calc conc " from a cell on the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create an automatic QC sheet from a set of experimental data.
I want to paste the data into excel and then write a command so it populates tables on a different sheet, allowing me to check QC quickly.
Every row in excel has data related to a specific sample. I want excel to populate a table that allows me to see the value of criteria (CV, concentration, recovery etc) for samples associated with a specific well.
The criteria are all column headings and everything in a specific row is related to a single sample.

I tried creating a basic sheet with "=" and then chose a cell on the data sheet, but each time we export the sheet, even sorting the data it may not end up in a specific cell, because of variation in sample names. However, each sample is always tied to the specific well. I want to use the well for Excel to find such a well, within a column and then extract other data from the same row.

For example, Well A01 contains a standard. I want to populate a table with CV, recovery, Calc conc mean. All these are on the same row as A01. Well, CV, Recovery and Calc conc mean are column headings. So when excel finds A01 it will take the CV value from the same row and put this in the table on a different sheet.

Comment: Without some example data, I would be considering index(), match(), if() and & to do the concatenation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.